# What does a "+=" operator inside a ternary operator means?

Tags: java

I came across a code snippet inside the androidx.lifecycle package and I was wondering what does this means.

```
LiveData.this.mActiveCount += mActive ? 1 : -1;
```

Where mActiveCount is an int, and mActive is a boolean.

But, as I was writting this question, I think I came with the answer, so if I'm not mistaken the "+=" operator, is used as we normally use the "=" operator.

This means that the order in which the code executes is the following:

the `mActive ? 1 : -1;` portion executes first.

Once this is resolved, the `LiveData.this.mActiveCount += mActive` executes. So my real question is:

Is this the correct equivalence of this code?:

```
    int intToAdd = mActive ? 1 : -1;
    activeCount += intToAdd;
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you @Progman.

Comment: Note that this code is unclear at a first glance and would be much improved by using parentheses: `mActiveCount += (mActive ? 1 : -1)`. (In addition, of course, to following Java conventions and not adding prefixes like `m`.)

Comment: Note that `+=` is not _inside_ the ternary expression but the ternary expression is an operand to `+=`.

Comment: I don't think it's unclear.  There's only one way to read it that I can find, even if you're a little unsure of order of operations.  Adding parenthesis would make it less clear imo.  @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: I didn't see chrylis's comment until after I gave my answer below, and I agree with him. One set of parens would make this statement much easier to read.

Comment: @markspace it's a [garden-path expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence), leading to a first binding of `mActive` as the RH operand of `+=`. The fact that you _can_ unambiguously reparse it doesn't eliminate the need to backtrack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The operator `+=` is not concerned with ternary operator.
You are checking for a condition using ternary operator and incrementing or decrementing it variable by 1.

```
a = a + b is equivalent to a += b, assuming we have declared a and b previously.
```

So, your code `LiveData.this.mActiveCount += mActive ? 1 : -1;` is equivalent to :-

```
 if(mActive){
    LiveData.this.mActiveCount += 1;
 }
 else{
   LiveData.this.mActiveCount -= 1;
 }
```

Your Logic below is also correct:-

```
 int intToAdd = mActive ? 1 : -1;
 activeCount += intToAdd;
```

Answer (score 3):

This line of code adds either 1 or -1 to `mAtiveCount`, and looks at the boolean `mActive` to determine whether it adds +1 or -1.

It is exactly equivalent to this chunk of code, where I removed the usage of the tertiary operator and the += operator (and made their function explicit):

```
int amountToAdd;
if (mActive) {
  amountToAdd = 1;
} else { 
  amountToAdd = -1;
}
LiveData.this.mActiveCount = LiveData.this.mActiveCount + amountToAdd;
```

I think the line is a bit unclear, but could be made more clear with the judicious use of parenthesis:

`LiveData.this.mActiveCount += (mActive ? 1 : -1);`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. There is something called as `shorthand` in java .

For example :

`sum = sum + 1` can be written as `sum += 1`.

This statement :

`LiveData.this.mActiveCount += mActive ? 1 : -1;`

This statement really mean to say :

Either do this `LiveData.this.mActiveCount += 1` or `LiveData.this.mActiveCount += -1` based on `mActive`'s value (true or false)

Comment: It's only answering half the question. (I'm not the downvote).

Answer (score 2):

This can be answered by looking up Java operator precedence.

Assignment operators have the absolute lowest precedence, everything else happens first. The conditional expression  `mActive ? 1 : -1` is evaluated first. then the += is evaluated using the result of the condition expression.